# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Also has getting this error ' No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}''

```
    const dnsListObj = {};
    for (const key of dnsList) {
      dnsListObj[key.id] = key.ipAddr;
    }
```

whats wrong in my code. please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
   const dnsListObj : {[key:string] : any } = {};

   
    for (const key in dnsList) {
      dnsListObj[key.id] = key.ipAddr;
    }
```

You can type your dnsListObj so it can accept indexes of type string

Comment: what's the syntax of `[key:string]` called?